# Simple 'checked' attribute changing by clicking on parent DIV

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have HTML DOM like:

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="list-group ">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start listItem" id="">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <span style="float: left; width: 100%;"> 
              <span style=" float: left; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 15px;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="cb_domain_sc">
              </span>
              <span style="width: 50px; float: left; ">
                <h5 class="mb-1">Supplychain</h5>
              </span> 
            </span>
            <small>3 days ago</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is to change the Input's markup 'checked' attribute by clicking on the DIV with `<div class="list-group ">  [...]`

I have many **DIVs** like this on the page, I tried to use some code with `$this` indicator but all failed.
I tried to `find()` or `first()` **function**.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: `$('.list-group').on('click', function () { $(this).find('[name="cb_domain_sc"]').prop('checked', true); });`? This is kind of basic jQuery.

Comment: can you post your code and so we can where things went wrong

Comment: You can not nest other interactive elements such a `input` into `a`, that's invalid HTML.

Comment: Like this? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5m7bm2n/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
$(body).on('click', '.list-group', function() {
    $(this)
        .find('input:checkbox')
        .prop('checked', true);
});
```

Or find by name:

```
$(body).on('click', '.list-group', function() {
    $(this)
        .find('input[name="cb_domain_sc"]')
        .prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: In such way, I would have to add a specific code to all DIVs separately cause of the unique name.

Comment: This works and will check only the inputs associated with the `.list-group` you clicked, no matter if is the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something like:

```
$( ".listItem" ).click(function() 
{
   $('Input', $(this)).prop('checked', true); 
}
```

Assuming there is only one Input markup inside ;)

Thanks, to All :)